# Error when storing users inputted data into a database with php

Tags: php, html, sql

I can't seem to fix this, Although i feel it is an issue with my syntax. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

'Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ']' in line 12' is the error being displayed.

```
?php
if ( ! empty( $_POST ) ) {

    $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', '111', '111', '111' );

    if ( $mysqli->connect_error ){
        die('connect error: ' . $mysqli->connect_errno. ': ' . $mysqli->connect_error );
    }

    $sql = "INSERT INTO processcv ( Name, Surname, Tel, Email, Message, CVtype) VALUES 
    ( '{$mysqli->cubrid_real_escape_string($_POST['Name'])}','
    ( '{$mysqli->cubrid_real_escape_string($_POST['Surname])}','
    ( '{$mysqli->cubrid_real_escape_string($_POST['Tel'])}','
    ( '{$mysqli->cubrid_real_escape_string($_POST['Email'])}','
    ( '{$mysqli->cubrid_real_escape_string($_POST['Message'])}',
    ( '{$mysqli->cubrid_real_escape_string($_POST['CVtype'])}' )";
    $insert = $mysqli->query($sql);

    if ( $insert ){
    echo "success! Row ID: {$mysqli->insert_id}";
    } else{
    die("error: {$mysqli->errno} : {$mysqli->error}");
    }

    $mysqli->close();

}
?>
```

Comment: You open a lot of parenthesis in your statement. You only want the first one. (But that's probably not related the error you get now. But it will generate an error later.)

Comment: kindly `echo $sql` and tell the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Their was syntax error unexpected use of `'` and way of variables called please check below

```
<?php
if ( ! empty( $_POST ) ) {

    $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', '111', '111', '111' );

    if ( $mysqli->connect_error ){
        die('connect error: ' . $mysqli->connect_errno. ': ' . $mysqli->connect_error );
    }

    $sql = "INSERT INTO processcv ( Name, Surname, Tel, Email, Message, CVtype) VALUES 
    ( '".$mysqli->cubrid_real_escape_string($_POST['Name'])."'),
    ( '".$mysqli->cubrid_real_escape_string($_POST['Surname'])."'),
    ( '".$mysqli->cubrid_real_escape_string($_POST['Tel'])."'),
    ( '".$mysqli->cubrid_real_escape_string($_POST['Email'])."'),
    ( '".$mysqli->cubrid_real_escape_string($_POST['Message'])."'),
    ( '".$mysqli->cubrid_real_escape_string($_POST['CVtype'])."')";
    $insert = $mysqli->query($sql);

    if ( $insert ){
    echo "success! Row ID: {$mysqli->insert_id}";
    } else{
    die("error: {$mysqli->errno} : {$mysqli->error}");
    }

    $mysqli->close();

}
?>
```

Comment: Hi Varun, Thanks for the reply. I am now getting the follow error that did not occur before: Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user '111'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in 'my directory' on line 4
connect error: 1045: Access denied for user '111'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: this error occured if your database  username or password is not right